# Problemas com Construtor de Queries (Query Builder) no Laravel 4.2

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, laravel-4, where

Olá,

estou com problemas para gerar uma querie utilizando o **Querie Builder** do **Laravel 4.2**, a dificuldade surge da necessidade de que as sentenças resultantes para pesquisa na base de dados estejam dentro de parenteses, abaixo esta a querie desejada:

```
select * from `EV_RELATORIO` 
    where `DTALTERACAO` between ? and ? and
         (`MUN_ID` is null or (`MUN_ID` in (?))) and
         (`REG_ID` is null or (`REG_ID` in (?)));
```

Porém esta retornando a seguinte querie:

```
select * from `EV_RELATORIO` 
    where `DTALTERACAO` between ? and ? and
          `MUN_ID` in (?) or `MUN_ID` is null and
          `REG_ID` in (?) or `MUN_ID` is null';
```

A construção da querie dentro da model utilizando o Laravel segue abaixo:
(Arquivo **VW_Relatorio.php**)

```
<?php

class VW_Relatorio extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'EV_RELATORIO';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    public function scopeMundos($query, $dados) {
        if(!empty($dados)){
            $query->whereIn('MUN_ID', $dados)->orWhereNull('MUN_ID');
        }
        return $query;
    }

     public function scopeRegionais($query, $dados) {
        if(!empty($dados)){
            $query->whereIn('REG_ID', $dados)->orWhereNull('MUN_ID');
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Faço a chamada na minha classe com o seguinte código:

```
$rel = \VW_Relatorio::whereBetween('DTALTERACAO',array($dataInicial, $dataFinal))
    ->mundos($data[0]['mundos'])
    ->regionais($data[0]['regionais'])
    ->get();
```

Tentei utilizar "Where" avançados, porém não conseguir gerar a querie corretamente.

Agradeço desde já a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que é assim, eu fiz direto sem colocar como `scope` se der certo é só transferir pra lá, a sintaxe é essa:.

```
$param1 = $data[0]['mundos'];
$param2 = $data[0]['regionais'];
$rel = \VW_Relatorio::whereBetween('DTALTERACAO',array($dataInicial, $dataFinal))
    ->where(function($query) use ($param1){
           $query->whereIn('MUN_ID', $param1)
                 ->orWhere(\DB::raw('MUN_ID is NULL')); 
    })
    ->where(function($query) use ($param2){
           $query->whereIn('REG_ID', $param2)
                 ->orWhere(\DB::raw('REG_ID is NULL'));
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, alterei minha Model e funcionou, com o detalhe que utilizei **"use"** no lugar de **"uses"**.

Comment: @LeandroJ.S.Paiva foi erro de digitação desculpas ... !!! que bom que funcionou!